# Error 10061 - Connecting to SAP from .Net

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to connect to SAP database from .NET application. I want to fetch a list of products from SAP database. I know nothing about SAP, trying to communicate using SAP .NET Connector.

I am not able to establish connection with SAP database successfully, getting `Error 10061 WSAECONNREFUSED`. I've disabled firewall as well.

I've configured my App.config as below.

```
 <configuration>
 
   <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="SAP.Middleware.Connector">
       <sectionGroup name="ClientSettings">
         <section name="DestinationConfiguration" type="SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationConfiguration, sapnco"/>
       </sectionGroup>
     </sectionGroup>   </configSections>
 
   <SAP.Middleware.Connector>    
     <ClientSettings>
       <DestinationConfiguration>
         <destinations>
           <add NAME="DEV" USER="username" PASSWD="password" CLIENT="000"
                LANG="EN" ASHOST="127.0.0.1" SYSNR="00"
                MAX_POOL_SIZE="10" IDLE_TIMEOUT="10"/>
         </destinations>
       </DestinationConfiguration>
     </ClientSettings>   </SAP.Middleware.Connector>
      <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>   </startup>
 
 </configuration>
```

Code in code is as below

```
 RfcDestination SapRfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("DEV");
 
 RfcRepository SapRfcRepository = SapRfcDestination.Repository;
```

I get the exception as soon as second statement is executed.

The Exception message is as below

```
LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
ERROR       partner 'WIN-FHT4V74IPIN:3300' not reached
TIME        Tue Dec 31 02:46:24 2013
RELEASE     720
COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
VERSION     40
RC          -10
MODULE      nixxi.cpp
LINE        3286
DETAIL      NiPConnect2: 192.168.100.123:3300
SYSTEM CALL connect
ERRNO       10061
ERRNO TEXT  WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
COUNTER     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network connection is down on the way. Wait, or call network administrator. You can verify it using

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3300
```

By the way, `127.0.0.1` is localhost ip address, are you sure it is right?

Comment: Network is fine. Still problem exists. I am running it on localhost, as SAP Business One is on same machine.